# Angular form Validators.pattern does not work for matching 2 variants

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a unique case where I have to validate either datetime format or empty string. Either of those should be valid input. But for example malformed or incomplete datetime should fail validation.

```
   myForm = this.form.group({
      ...
      ts: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|^(?=\s*$)$/')]],
   });
```

Template:

```
       <input
          type="datetime-local"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="ts">
```

I checked my regex in https://regex101.com/ and it matches empty input or proper datetime format like `2023-09-14T17:17`

However when in my app I leave the field empty, it still shows validation error.

Can anyone recommend anything else I might be missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try to print out in HTML with `{{ myForm.get('ts').errors | json }}` and see what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

It's `Validators.required` that is returing an error on empty string not your `Validators.pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex is matching empty string and that is acceptable then you can remove `Validators.required`.
You can write it like this:

```
 myForm = this.form.group({
      ...
      ts: ['', [Validators.pattern('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|^(?=\s*$)$/')]],
   });
```

Hope this helps!